# Service fabric debugging - reliablecollection persisted?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can't seem to find any information on whether a `ReliableCollection`, specifically `ReliableQueue` is persisted between debugging sessions in visual studio.  It does not seem like it is.  I think it's because the application is removed and then re-added during debugging.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default behavior is to remove the deployed application after the debugger stops.
Fortunately, you can [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37923884/5946937) this.

> 1. There are two ways this can be done: Launch your app from VS without
>    the debugger attached (Debug -> Start Without Debugging [Ctrl+F5]).
>    Obviously, this would require you to manually attach VS to your
>    service processes in order to debug them. When you detach VS from the
>    processes, VS will not remove the application in this scenario.
> 2. With
>    your Application (.sfproj) project selected in Solution Explorer, go
>    to the Properties window and change Application Debug Mode from
>    "Remove" to "Auto Upgrade". This prevents VS from removing the
>    application after debugging. However, it also causes another change in
>    behavior in that it will automatically upgrade your application each
>    time you launch it from VS. The added benefit of auto upgrade is that
>    your application state will be maintained across multiple launches
>    from VS. This may be desired or not. There is not a setting that
>    allows you to both prevent application removal and not do an auto
>    upgrade.