# Azure Service Fabric gets terminated in local cluster when running tests

Tags: azure-service-fabric

So we are using Azure Service Fabric and gets a weird behavior when trying to run API tests against my local development cluster.

Every time I start the test the app gets terminated, sometimes it gets restarted again but most often it just stays terminated (and even deleted from the cluster).

I guess its somehow connected against that when I run the API test it will run and build stuff that the service fabric is using, but since the outcome is different depending on something (maybe the sun?) it feels like I am either missing something or experience a bug with service fabric.

Do anyone have any idea? Consider me as a noob and assume that I have done something wrong myself (I am doing that atleast).

**UPDATE**

There was a question on how we do run our tests:

1. Starts 2 instances of Visual Studio
2. Open the same `.sln` in both of them
3. Start the Service Fabric project.
4. Wait until cluster reports OK.
5. Run api test through a unit test (both service bus tests and REST tests) with Resharper test runner

Now we get the messages that is attached in diagnostics.

Diagnostics:

Event #1

```
{   
 "Timestamp": "2018-10-16T08:14:03.0590414+02:00",  
 "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",   
 "Id": 23083,   
 "Message": ApplicationHostTerminated:   ApplicationId=fabric:/<MyService>,      ServiceName=fabric:/<MyService>,  ServicePackageName=<MyPackage>,      ServicePackageActivationId=8f36ac97-9271-4a49-94ce-dd296aebffa5,      IsExclusive=True,  CodePackageName=Code,  EntryPointType=Exe,      ExeName=MyExe,  ProcessId=24568, HostId=d2a820b5-5b4d-42af-ae87-350028a3fa72,  ExitCode=3221225786, UnexpectedTermination=False,  StartTime=10/16/2018 08:12:14. ",  
 "ProcessId": 22660,   
 "Level": "Informational",   
 "Keywords": "0x4000000000000001",   
 "EventName": "Hosting",   
 "ActivityID": null, 
 "RelatedActivityID": null,   
 "Payload": {
     "eventInstanceId": "\"07f15452-2f75-49e3-ad5d-d16ea49bdc8f\"",
     "applicationName": "MyAppName",
     "ServiceName": "fabric:/MyServiceName",
     "ServicePackageName": "MyPackageName",
     "ServicePackageActivationId": "8f36ac97-9271-4a49-94ce-dd296aebffa5",
     "IsExclusive": true,
     "CodePackageName": "Code",
     "EntryPointType": 1,
     "ExeName": "MyExe",
     "ProcessId": 24568,
     "HostId": "d2a820b5-5b4d-42af-ae87-350028a3fa72",
     "ExitCode": 3221225786,
     "UnexpectedTermination": false,
     "StartTime": "\"\/Date(1539670334917)\/\""   
 } 
}
```

Event #2

```
{   
 "Timestamp": "2018-10-16T08:14:02.3557708+02:00",  
 "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",   
 "Id": 29625,   
 "Message": "Application deleted: Application = fabric:/MyApp, Application Type = MyServiceType ",   
 "ProcessId": 22660,   
 "Level": "Informational",  
 "Keywords": "0x4000000000000001",   
 "EventName": "CM",   
 "ActivityID": null,   
 "RelatedActivityID": null,   
 "Payload": {
     "eventInstanceId": "\"ca608cec-8d55-4606-a331-8ebfcfff8fa6\"",
     "applicationName": "fabric:/MyAppName",
     "applicationTypeName": "MyAppTypeName",
     "applicationTypeVersion": "1.0.0"   
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information of how do you execute API test? For example: 1) build & deploy application on local cluster. 2) run my the testing tool.

Comment: Sure, i have updated the question.

Comment: Are you starting the Service Fabric project through the F5? Does this situation happen if you publish the Service Fabric project to local cluster (using Publish functionality) and then run the tests?

Comment: Correct I start through F5. We want to have the debugger on when doing this when for example investigating a bug.

Comment: And regarding publish, that works as long as I dont attach the debugger

Comment: I think you may experience this VS behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37923884/5946937

Comment: Not really. It's the opposite. I want to debug it, not stop the debugger and keep the cluster running.

Comment: @MikaelJohansson I think you can experience a side effect of [application debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio#application-debug-modes) set for your `.sfproj`. I think it is set to default **Refresh Application** or **Remove Application**. Can you try to set it to **Keep Application**? This should prevent the Visual Studio to recreate the application during debugging session.

Comment: I agree, i did try to change to Auto Upgrade and that did "solve" the issue for me. So most likely Keep Application would also "solve" it.

Thanks for taking some time for me!

Comment: @Oleg: Could you write your last comment as a suggested answer? Then I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can experience a side effect of [Application Debug Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio#application-debug-modes) set for your `.sfproj`.

By default **Application Debug Mode** is set to `Refresh Application` (which if you are using 5-node cluster is automatically changed to `Remove Application`) or `Remove Application` debug mode. This instructs Visual Studio to recreate the application for each debugging session and remove it when session ends.

Changing it to `Keep Application` should prevent the Visual Studio from recreating the application during debugging session.